# i created a react native project in windows system but when i want to run in ios OS using npx react-native run-ios it gives me permission denied erro

Tags: reactjs, react-native

AppCoderiOS1:ios appcoderios1$ npx react-native start
sh: /Users/appcoderios1/Downloads/ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/react-native: Permission denied
gives me the error when an existing project created in windows OS want to run in ios OS

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you can't run iOS project in machine with Windows.
You can run project in iOS emulator only if you have MacOS.

Comment: the problem arise in Mac os for ios

Comment: You get this error when you run `npx react-native run-ios` ?

Comment: yes , i get error when run npx react-native run-ios